# Do we need a [profanity] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/would-publishers-accept-a-title-which-includes-the-f-word) @Cyn used the [sex](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) tag since there was no profanity or swearing tag. I feel this tag should be reserved for the questions about sex in writing.

Instead I propose we have a [profanity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity) tag for these kind of questions. A [simple search](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=swearing) reveals a lot of questions that should be tags this way.

Should we have a [profanity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profanity) tag? Would [swearing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing) be better?

If we decide yes, should we re-tag the old questions from that search?

Comment: I'm fine with adding [profanity].  I think that's better than [swearing] (which can also have a legal meaning).  Since there are questions that ask about it explicitly, it makes sense to have it for them.

Comment: [profanity] yes, [swearing] - no. 'Swearing' can also mean other things, it is unclear.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Your search affects [23 questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=swearing+is%3Aq), so people should review them and see which should get the tag, and then do them in a few batches over the weekend maybe?

Comment: Also [profanity] yes, [swearing] no. I can imagine quite a few questions in Writing about any profanity, and many of us write scenes for adult readers involving explicit violence or sex or more authentic language amongst criminals. Not for children or young adults.

Comment: I have added the tag to a bunch of questions and written both a definition and an excerpt. I'm happy with the excerpt but maybe the definition needs some fucking work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some time ago [I made a little list](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/23159) of how I judge new tags for the meta question [I'd like some guidance on creating tags](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497/23159).

1. Ask yourself how many questions you have about this topic: is this probably the only one or is this a topic you want to ask about more regularly?

   - I think this topic comes up sometimes and people might be interested enough in it to search for a tag and all related questions. Plus point towards creating this tag for choosing a tag name that fits a broader topic, that still has clear boundaries judging by the name.
2. Look through the existing questions: how many already use the word or similar words and might profit from the tag?

   - We already have a couple of questions that need this. You did some good research about how often this would be used. Thanks! Looks good, plus point.
3. Look through the existing tags: is one of them already encompassing what you are trying to convey?

   - Again, you did your research, and I can't find anything that already encompasses this. You also mentioned how [sex](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) is insufficient for this use case. Another plus point for creating this tag.
4. Look through Meta: have there been similar requests or precedent cases where something similar has been created/denied?

   - There has only been one question on meta mentioning "profanity" and that was [Are profanity and expletives appropriate on Writers.SE?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/546/23159), which was about using profanity. Asking about the usage of profanity *in your writing* seems to be appropriate as long as you are asking in a professional way. Don't swear when communicating with other users, but do ask about the usage of swear words in your novel. Plus point again.
5. Think about the sites scope: do you think that a lot of people will profit from these tags when they are asking questions about the specific topic of the site you are on?

   - It's a topic that is important in a lot of writing styles as many people swear in their day-to-day life and therefore in some genres it's expected. It is certainly something I would find information about on a site like ours. Plus point.
6. Think about the tag's scope: is it well-defined and obvious to users coming to the site?

   - The tag looks pretty self-explanatory to me given the site scope. Plus.

All in all looks like a clear plus from my side for creating the tag and retagging the relevant questions.

The tag was added two days ago by [Lauren Ipsum](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/do-we-need-a-profanity-tag#comment4746_1842), even with an excerpt and a longer description that show what the tag is about. That was the last thing that I mentioned in my original list about creating tags.

Thank you Lauren, f@$%ing awesome of you! :D

Comment: My bloody pleasure. ;)